# Stable CPU frequency on imx6s

Tags: arm, embedded, imx6

I want to make CPU frequency on imx6s based board unchangeable. Even WFI call shouldn't affect. So far I see the significant CPU frequency drop during processor stays in WFI mode.

According to [technical reference manual for imx6s](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/IMX6SDLRM.pdf) the low power mode, the processor will be transfered after `WFI`, is configured by `LPM` bits of `CLPCR` register (page 855). I have set LPM bits to 0x0 what is mentioned as RUN mode. From my understanding this should be enough not to put processor in any kind of sleep mode (WAIT or STOP on imx).

Is there something else behind this? Am i missing something here?

Suppose I use non-linux custom environment.

---

Appendix (how and what i measure):

The experiment looks the following:
1. With WFI

```
p1 = ArmPmuGetCpuCycles()
Sleep(100 miliseconds)   <- here it goes to WFI
p2 = ArmPmuGetCpuCycles()
p2 - p1 = 600 microseconds
```

2. Without WFI

```
p1 = ArmPmuGetCpuCycles()
Sleep(100 miliseconds)   <- WFI is removed
p2 = ArmPmuGetCpuCycles()
p2 - p1 = 100 miliseconds
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve.  There are low power clocks that are active in all modes at a fixed frequency.  Did you want a higher time base to measure finer grain, but over a sleep mode transition?  Also, some things depend on the hardware design (what will have power when and what crystals/OSC are available).  Also,  the tag [tag:linux-kernel] is a little misleading?

Comment: @artlessnoise "Did you want a higher time base to measure finer grain, but over a sleep mode transition" - Yes. I want CPU clocks to be enabled during WFI transition, because I use PMU conunter for time measurement. And i don't know if there is a Sleep() somwhere in between or not. I use PMU counter, because it is the most fast clock source in the system. About linux-kernel tag - please ignore it.

Comment: That is counter intuitive and not really something any normal person would want, so I expect the chip designers probably don't allow it to prevent an error.  Why would you use `WFI` and keep the CPU clock enabled.  That defeats the purpose of `WFI`?  If it is for debug and you have physical access you can use a GPIO toggle and a scope.  The delta should be very accurate.

Comment: That not defeat the purpose of WFI, because WFI is not only about CPU clocks sundowning. You may want to preserve CPU clocks in order to avoid any kind of latency. "I expect the chip designers probably don't allow it to prevent an error" - as I said before - what is the meaning of LPM bits = RUN mode in CLPCR register ? (see the question body).

Comment: `WFI` is to conserve energy.  Keeping the CPU clocks active will not conserve energy especially when the CPU is in a static state.  I guess DDR is not accessed, but keeping the CPU clock active is probably not much more energy than a spin loop in cache.  The modes are defined elsewhere in the doc; RUN is the highest power 'sleep' mode.  See page 817.  You can use the CCGR to enable an EPIT and use that as a time source.  ARM core is hard coded so logic there is not configurable (easily) by Freescale/NXP.  If it is possible look at ARM docs, not NXP.

Comment: Could you explain "ARM core is hard coded so logic there is not configurable (easily) by Freescale/NXP."? You mean WFI performs CPU clocks shut-downing inside ARM core itself? So even NXP clock and control modules preserve the clock, the clock is shut downed inside of the CPU core because of WFI instruction?

Comment: I mean it maybe gated off by the CPU logic.  The oscillator may still run external.  Crystals take very little energy.  It is the transistors that they switch which are the issue.  So the PMU may shutdown (by ARM logic) when an WFI is seen.  After all, 'performance mearsuring' of an IDLE CPU doesn't make sense.  The timebase of the EPIT is very high is it not?  Polled mode EPIT routines have small code size and are fairly easy to implement.  You need to look at the TRM and ARM ARM docs.  There are usually (other 2 SOCs I used) nebulous references to some ARM signals in the NXP docs.

Comment: @artlessnoise I think you are right, looks like the manual for cortex-a9 confirms this. You can post this as an answer if you would like to.  About EPIT - I know that, but this approach have some complications now, i don't want to dive into details (+ the time base is lower than for pmu counter). Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

CPU sleep modes and DVFS frequency setting are normally orthogonal power saving techniques.

WFI can generally trigger clock gating (stop clock logic which is known to be idle waiting for an interrupt, but doesn't normally change frequencies or voltages as these can be quite slow operations). Dynamically changing voltages and frequencies is normally handled by a higher-level kernel driver such as Cpufreq.

One of the main inputs into DVFS policies which drive dynamic CPU frequencies is utilization, so if your software is spending a lot of time in the OS idle loop (which will call WFI internally) then the higher level logic is going to decide you are under utilizing the CPU and start to drop frequencies to save power.

**Update** Given you are measuring frequency using the PMU, then what you are seeing is the PMU stopping to increment due to clock gating rather than a frequency change. Generally if you want to keep some notion of system time you will need a timer peripheral which doesn't get put into lower power mode; these are widely available for exactly this use case, but may have a coarser measurement granularity.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. "Suppose I use non-linux custom environment." I don't have any dvfs in my RTOS.

Comment: You may consider it as complete clock shut downing. I guess i see some tick progress because of timer interrupt which wakes the processor from wfi to run mode periodically.

Comment: Yep - just seen your update on the question. The PMU will stop incrementing if the CPU gets clock gated. during WFI. Answer updated.

Comment: I don't want to use timer because the available frequencies for them are not high enough (because of clock tree structure). The CPU ref clock is the highest. Anyway my question is not about what you have answered. I'am asking why CPU clock is gated, while according to the bits i set in CLPCR it shouldn't be. Anyway, big thanks for your effort.